# Generate new address in Ethereum node using Json-RPC

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, addresses

Well, first of all, I am very new to Ethereum and maybe I am asking something stupid but my question is the following. I feel comfortable using json-rpc commands and I want to know how can I create a new Ethereum address.
In bitcoind the method that I am searching for is "getnewaddress" but I don't know if there is another way to do it in Ethereum. If someone could help me I'd be grateful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#creating-accounts) :

> Creating a new account

```
 geth account new
```

> Creates a new account and prints the address.
>
> On the console, use:

```
 personal.newAccount("passphrase")
```

Over RPC (insecure solution)

```
  curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"personal_newAccount","params":["passowrd"],"id":74}' http://localhost:8545
```

to use it you need to enable the personal Api `geth --rpc --rpcapi "personal,eth,web3"`
more details : https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#personal_newaccount

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I want create the address using json-rpc (I forgot to mention it, I edited the title now)

Comment: check my edit then

Comment: Okay, thank you! If you know, could you explain me the reason that method is insecure? Because I am working on a project where I will have a website and each user can generate new Ethereum address

Comment: I think you should open a new post to benefit from the others opinion.besides  there is some others post discussing this issue https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/search?q=rpc+secure

Comment: when I perform this command get error "local keystore not used". Described more here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102476/rpc-personal-newaccount-returns-code-32000-messagelocal-keystore-not-use