# Is there any api for creating the wallet and transfer the ETH coin to wallet to wallet?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, myetherwallet

Please suggest me? Which api should be the better option and is ethereum does not provide any api ? or we only need to access third party api?

Comment: sorry this is late! I hope this helps and reach out if you need some assistance or require other features

Answer (score 1):

If you run a node (e.g. [Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) or [Parity](https://parity.io/)) then you are able to expose a lot of functionality to yourself / your code via [JSON RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) or the IPC interface.

> Is there any api for creating the wallet

You can find the answer to creating a new account via JSON RPC, and what you should be wary of when doing so, in other questions such as [this one](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15801/generate-new-address-in-etherum-node-using-json-rpc).

> Is there any api to transfer the ETH coin to wallet to wallet?

You can transfer Ether using the [eth.sendTransaction](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) function of the RPC interface / API e.g.

```
var sender = eth.accounts[0];
var receiver = eth.accounts[1];
var amount = web3.toWei(0.1, "ether");

eth.sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running your own node and still wish to use Ethereum, and other supported tokens use [bloopi](https://bloopi.io).

Bloopi supports a number of things with ruby and has a [RESTFUL interface](https://bloopi.io/docs) if you wish to not use ruby:

Install:

```
gem install bloopi
```

Auth:

```
require 'bloopi'
Bloopi::API::Auth.new(client_id='', client_secret='').get_access_token
```

New wallet

```
args = {password:'[hidden]'}
ether_wallet = Bloopi::API::Ether.new_wallet(args)
```

Ether balance

```
args = {"address":"0xad96B1072E60f6279F628E7512242F9b1A83127F"}
ether_balance = Bloopi::API::Ether.balance(args)
```

Send Ether

```
Bloopi::API::Ether.transfer({:to_address=>"0xE4E3A170843C6fdF2D480592D20eC27985Bc05Dd", :from_address=>"0x7e3513840f6936efe9cc96c279917af6e3be682b", :password=>"[hidden]", :quantity=>0.0001})
```

Exchange Ether for OmiseGo

```
 Bloopi::API::Ether.exchange({:deposit_address=>"0x00c02245d47e1EE134B67C8a4e035C0A063fce2D", :from_address=>"0xdaa0dcc41d89e060e619cafe0c09e6a637b0f8ac", :password=>"[hidden]", :quantity=>0.05215999999999999})
```

OmiseGo balance

```
args = {wallet_address:""}
Bloopi::API::OmiseGo.balance(args)
```

Send OmiseGo

```
args = {to_address:"", from_address:"", password:"", quantity:0.001}
Bloopi::API::OmiseGo.transfer(args)
```

ERC20 token balance

```
args = {wallet_address:"", contract_address:""}
Bloopi::API::Token.balance(args)
```

Send ERC20 token

```
args = {to_address:"", from_address:"", password:"", quantity:0.001, contract_address:""}
Bloopi::API::Token.transfer(args)
```